# Why does malloc overwrite previous allocation if pointer is passed in as size?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I have the following C code and I can't quite understand the behavior of `malloc` here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
        size_t* v3;
        char *message;
        size_t size;
        v3 = malloc(10uLL);
        *v3 = 1LL;
        printf("first address: %p\n", (void *)v3);
        size = 0;
        scanf("%lu", &size);
        message = malloc(size);
        read(0, message, size);
        message[size-1] = 0;
        write(1, message, size);
        if(!*v3) printf("you win");
        else printf("you didn't win");
        return 0;
}
```

So the program allocates some memory and we print the address. Now, if I use this address as a number and add 1 to it and then provide it as a size for the next `malloc` then when `message[size-1] = 0` happens it basically overflows and modifies `v3`. It was set to `1LL` but after that it is `0` and "you win" is printed.

Can someone please explain how this happens?

As suggested in the comments this is what happens when I run the program:

First output is: `first address: 0x5581cb0646b0`
Then I just open a python shell and do: `int("0x5581cb0646b0", 16) + 1` which converts the hex value to a number and add `1` to it which gives `94015945328305`

I provide this to `scanf` and then `read` runs but the message can be anything here, won't change what happens.

Finally, the message and then "you win" is printed. (but notice that `*v3` should be `1LL` not `0`.

Comment: I suggest that `(void *)&v3` should be `(void *)v3`. I can't see any sense in "address as a number and add 1 to it and then provide it as a size."

Comment: `message[size-1] = 0 happens it basically overflows and modifies v3` Are you expecting that return values from malloc are continuous? Is this a theoretical example? Did you actually executed the program? `how this happens?` Please post the output from the execution of the program.

Comment: My guess is that the `scanf` fails so `size` is still zero, and then `message[size-1] = 0` corrupts memory because the index is out of range.

Comment: Added an example execution to the original post. @RaymondChen I don't think that's the case, because providing any other similar value causes a seg fault.

Comment: This is a short enough program that you should be able to debug it line by line to see who is changing `*v3`.

Comment: malloc(very large number) returns 0.  You should print out some of your intermediate values.

Comment: `malloc` does **not** overwrite previous allocations: the problem is in this very strange code that does not check anything, and does not report "before" and "after".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging and research I found the solution. So just for the context, this is a CTF challenge that I'm trying to understand how to exploit. Turns out the key point I missed is that if you take the address of `v3` that is printed on the screen and add `1` to it and pass that to the `scanf` which is then used as the size for the second `malloc`, it is too big and `malloc` will return `0`. However, `message[size - 1]` is basically just `0` + `size` (which is the address of `v3 + 1`) `-1` which is then the exact address of `v3` which makes it possible to change the value to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

v3 is allocated a certain memory block, after that you allocated another memory block to message.
there's a good chance that they are contiguous blocks of memory and message is 8 bytes pass v3, BUT you are not suppose to rely on this behavior since malloc can give you a pointer to an address from anywhere it deems fit, so it is definitely undefined what should happen
and just cause that's the results you get doesn't mean it's the results you should rely on every time.

another thing to consider is what metadata malloc'd pointers might hold which is dependent on the implementation of malloc and is hidden from "us" the users, malloc can certainly hold metadata at the end of the allocated pointer for all we know, if you want to truly test malloc without causing undefined behavior you should run it with vlg to make sure you are not doing anything that might produce unreliable results.

do you mind trying to explain what exactly you tried to do in this code and how did you get to it?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce a ctf challenge and understand the trick used to make this work.